# display blank page in production

Tags: symfony

Currently working on Symfony2, I'm trying to make my website work on a server on production environment.
But I get a blank page, it's OK on developpement environment.

Some things I saw :

- No log file on app/logs
- No specific error on Apache error log

With Firebug, I see a `HTTP Error 500` for `GET /web/`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are in  your log ? Did you try to refresh cache ? is it a problem of your conf_prod vs conf_dev ...?

Comment: OK got it ! My virtualhost was wrong. I added /web to the path and now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen if you use `{{ dump(var) }}` and the var has nested arrays.  Try removing any dump, and if that does not work, tryign removing any variables you are using in twig to display a static page.

You may want to manually delete the prod cache and install assets again for prod mode.  See [Symfony Production Checklist](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) for a list of basic steps with D and E covering the cache and assets.